# Add a content type as a select list when creating a new user

Tags: 6, users

I have a content type called Location.

Each user needs a location assigned to them.

How do I go about attaching the Location to the user?

Basically I need to add a dropdown of locations that I can select from for each user I create/edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use/add the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module, you can use it to create a profile for each user. In that profile content, you can have a field that is a node reference back to the Location type you mention.

> This module builds user profiles as content (aka nodes), which opens the opportunity to use all the powerful modules for content for user profiles too, e.g. the Content Construction Kit (CCK). It's intended to be simple and useful, but extensible by further modules.
>
> Content profiles can be restricted to certain roles; the module also supports separate content profiles for different roles.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Content Profile](http://drupal.org/project/content_profile) module.

> This module builds user profiles as content (aka nodes), which opens the opportunity to use all the powerful modules for content for user profiles too, e.g. the Content Construction Kit (CCK). It's intended to be simple and useful, but extensible by further modules.
>
> Content profiles can be restricted to certain roles; the module also supports separate content profiles for different roles.
>
> Content profile is the successor of the Drupal 5 Node Profile and Bio modules. The intention is to have a common "profiles-as-nodes" base module upon which further extension modules can rely.